# Can the power button be disabled while using an app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am making an alarm app for Android. Is there a way to disable the volume control and the phone's power button from within the app? If the app needs to ask the user for permission before doing this, thats fine.

Comment: This strikes me as a _very_ bad idea. You can prevent sleep mode from happening but stopping the user from performing a task like powering down is almost certain to have your app removed quick time.

Comment: Disabling power button is not possible. Hmmm.. For security reasons? or you can customize it on firmware.

Comment: i think no coz for the sake of user security

Comment: its the only option when you are not getting good response so its a very bad if it could too so i recommend don't do that ppl may dislike this or not may definitely they will as we think